# Removing a word in a string (RemoveString)

Tags: java, string

So basically what I need help I need help doing is removing a word from a sting. I dont know how to use array, char and such just for those who refer me to that.

```
Output Ex: 
Enter a sentence: I really like Jolly Ranchers.

Enter a string: really

I like Jolly Ranchers.
```

I just need to remove every occurrence of the string from the sentence essentially. Thanks for help in advance!

(Not looking for a handout, perhaps pseudocode or another example.)

Comment: Look into using the String classes `replace` method

Comment: Look at `regex` and `String.replaceAll()`...

Answer (score 0):

You can go this way :

```
public static String remove(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence :");
        String sentence = sc .nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a word :");
        String word = sc .nextLine();
        String res ="";
        for(String words : sentence.split(" ")){
            if(!words.equalsIgnoreCase(word)){    //or words!=word if you want to NOT ignore the case
                res+=words+" ";
            }
        }
        return res;
    }   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(remove());
}
```

It looks every word, and keep only the ones who are not equals to the word you enter

Or a more with a more shorter way :

```
public static String remove(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence :");
        String sentence = sc .nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a word :");
        String word = sc .nextLine();
        return sentence.replaceAll(word,"");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use replaceAll function,
this function gets two params

1. regex - the string you want to replace
2. substr- the string to replace it with
   example:

   `newString = str1.replaceAll(regex, substr);`

newString is the edited string

str1 is the string you wish to edit

Answer (score 0):

[String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) works for that

```
package se.samples;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordRemover {
    static final String welcomeMessage = "Enter a sentence: ", 
            secondMessage = "Enter a string: ", 
            resultMessage = "";

    static String replace(String source, String that){
        return source.replaceAll(that, "");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.print(welcomeMessage);
        try(Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)){
            String input = s.nextLine();
            System.out.print(secondMessage);
            System.out.println(resultMessage + replace(input, s.nextLine()));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
 String[] s = originalString.split(" ");
    String wordToRemove = StandardInput;
    String finalString ="";
    for(String word : s){
    if(!word.equals(wordToRemove )){
    System.out.Print(word);
    finalString += word+" ";
          }
    }
```

Comment: Before posting any code, please do test it so as to make sure it actually works and doesn't generate any exceptions. This will just confuse and frustrate new people coming into the Java language that may want to utilize your general code concept which is good and can be applied for many different coding applications (I'm sure). A brief explanation of the code or comments within the code is helpful as well. I have not down voted this post since I'm sure you will correct it.

Answer (score -2):

I believe strings have a replace method so try something like str.replace("really", "") or replaceEach if there will be more than one. I suggest looking at the Java API for more functions.

Comment: I could have down voted this but instead I thought I would just let everyone know, the replaceEach() method is a Apache Commons StringUtils method which should have been indicated within this answer. String.replaceAll() will do the trick without the need for Apache unless of course your already utilizing it. ;)

Comment: ah yes, thank you for taking time from helping others to beat down the new kid. How quaint of you.